# Swift error: "cannot invoke >= with argument of list type (@lvalue CGPoint, CGPoint)"?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am trying to write an if statement saying if `block1`'s position exceeds a certain point, have this happen to `block3` . However when I try to compare using `>=` I get the error:"cannot invoke >= with argument of list type (@lvalue CGPoint, CGPoint)"

Here is the code:

```
 if block1.position >= CGPoint(self.size.width * 0.35,700) {

        block3.hidden = false
        block3.runAction(moveDownLeft)
        }
```

block1 is an SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGPoint is a struct. CMD-Click on it to see the definition:

```
struct CGPoint {
  var x: CGFloat
  var y: CGFloat
}
```

Compare the single elements and you're done.

Comment: Just an addition to this, you could also overload the >= operator to handle CGPoints if you are commonly checking this comparison in your code. More info can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html in the overloading operators section.

Comment: That's correct. The reason for the non-existance is: is (2|-1) greater than (0|0) (since the x is greater; but y is less)? So you need to overload that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if p2 > p1 then p2 is above p1 and p2 is on the right of p1
func >=(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x >= rhs.x && lhs.y >= rhs.y
}

// if p2 < p1 then p2 is below p1 and p2 is on the left of p1
func <=(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x <= rhs.x && lhs.y <= rhs.y
}
```

Also posted on [this page](http://swiftnow.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/how-to-design-logical-comparison-between-two-points/)